# Analytical solution to polynomial system

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have a polynomial system with three equations and three unknowns i wish to solve analytically. I can obtain a numerical solution easily but for my project i need to find a analytical solution. The system is 
$$(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y+a)^2+z^2=r_{1}^2$$
$$(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y+a)^2+z^2=r_{2}^2$$
$$(y+a)^2+z^2=r_{3}^2$$

where $a$ and the $r_{i}$ are constants.

I think the problem can be stated as the intersection between three elliptical cylinders. But I don't know if that helps or how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us change variables defining
$$X=\frac{\sqrt 3}2 x \qquad\qquad Y=\frac 12 y -a\qquad \qquad Z=z^2$$ to make
$$(X-Y)^2+Z=r_1^2\tag 1$$
$$(X+Y)^2+Z=r_2^2\tag 2$$
$$(2Y+a)^2+Z=r_3^2\tag 3$$

Subtracting $(1)$ for $(2)$ gives
$$X=\frac{r_2^2-r_1^2}{4 Y}\tag 4$$ and $(3)$ gives
$$Z=r_3^2-(2Y+a)^2\tag 5$$ All of that makes
$$48 Y^4+64 a Y^3+8  \left(2 a^2+r_1^2+r_2^2-2 r_3^2\right)Y^2-(r_1^4+r_2^4-2 r_1^2
   r_2^2)=0\tag 6$$ that you can solve with radicals (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) and have fun !).

You will have at most four real roots but, more than likely, some of them will  be discarded because of $(5)$ ($Z$ must be positive).

When solved, go back to $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Thank you for the derivation. Now i know how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With the last equation you will get
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y+a\right)^2+r_3^2-(y+a)^2=r_1^2$$
$$\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}y+a\right)^2+r_3^2-(y+a)^2=r_2^2$$
Subtracting both equations you will get
$$\sqrt{3}r_1^2-\sqrt{3}r_2^2-6xa+3xy=0$$

Comment: Thank you to all downvoters!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are missing the $x$ inside the first set of parentheses in your first two lines.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Just corrected!

Comment: Your conclusion is still wrong. Maybe the downvoters had a point?

Comment: Ok, so tell me where i'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, i'm waiting, where is my conclusion wrong?

Comment: It looks like your subsequent edit fixed it. And that's an awfully aggressive tone to have here.

Comment: Ok, my tone should be not agressive, it was a typo, sorry! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very useful.